# Dart how to clone a List of Maps

Tags: list, dictionary, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get several values from a list of maps but whenever I alter the new List values, it also alters the same values in the original list of maps.

How can I clone the list properly so this doesn't happen?

```
final List<Map> entries = [
  {'date': '2019-7-29', 'data': 85.0},
  {'date': '2019-8-2', 'data': 85.0},
  {'date': '2019-8-3', 'data': 85.0},
];

  List<Map> getSelected() {
    List<Map> obj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      obj.add(entries[i]);
      obj[i]['data'] = obj[i]['data'] * 2;
    }
    return obj;
  }

  selected = getSelected();
```

EDIT: This was suggested but doesn't appear to fix things. I guess because objects are passed by reference.

```
  List<Map> getSelected(List<Map> arr) {
    List<Map> obj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      obj.add(arr[i]);
      obj[i]['data'] = obj[i]['data'] * 2;
    }
    return obj;
  }

  selected = getSelected(entries);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final List<Map> entries = [
      {'date': '2019-7-29', 'data': 85.0},
      {'date': '2019-8-2', 'data': 85.0},
      {'date': '2019-8-3', 'data': 85.0},
    ];

List<Map> selected = new List<Map>();
entries.forEach((map) => { selected.add(new Map.from(map)) });
selected.forEach((map) => map["data"] = map["data"] * 2 );
```

would solve your issue.

Comment: This looks interesting, but your code doesn't do what my function `getSelected()` does. You're getting the values from `entires` without changing any of the values.

Comment: It is the way to clone it without sharing the same map references. you can use it also for modifications. What about considering cloning and data updates  in different steps. 

 
  `entries.forEach((map) => { entries2.add(new Map.from(map)) });`
  `entries2.forEach((map) => map["data"] = map["data"] * 2 );`

Comment: Yes it's a good solution. If you update your answer so it does the same as my original code like this I can accept it as the best answer.